# Как сделать видимыми dots только скрытых слайдов?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css3, slick.js

Всем привет!
У меня есть шесть слайдов, и соответсвующие им шесть dots. Из шести слайдов инициализировано в слик и видимы только два, трейтий видимый искуственно, через transform: translateX(-50%) (только так корректно отрабатывает зацыкленный слайдер под мои размеры и требования) . Слайдер зацыкленный.

Мне нужно выводить всегда только по три dots скрытых слайдов, соответственно dots третьего искуственно видимого слайда тоже нужно скрывать.

Я нахожу все дотсы и скрываю их. Добавила для дотсов классы before и after, которые сделают видимыми нужные дотсы. В кооментариях js подписано, что делают строчки, но я туплю и не могу правильно настроить логику, чтобы выводились только три дотса скрытых слайдов, и при клике на дотс, слайды передвигались. И может еще кто знает как дершание с шестого по седьмой слайд пофиксить(предпологаю, что это из-за transform: translateX(-50%))

Хелп ми плииииз!)

```js
$(".slider").slick({
  infinite: true,
 slidesToScroll: 1,
 slidesToShow: 2,
  dots: true
});
    var dots = $('.slick-dots li');
    //вешаем обработчик на наши точки
    dots.click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        dots.removeClass('before after');
        //отображаем 2 следующие точки
        $this
            .next().addClass('after')
            .next().addClass('after')
            .next().addClass('after');


        //если мы в самом начале - добавляем пару последующих точек
        if(!$this.prev().length) {
            $this.next().next().next()
                .addClass('after').next()
                .addClass('after').next().next()
                .addClass('after');
        }
        //на 2й позиции - добавляем одну точку
        if(!$this.prev().prev().length) {
            $this.next().next().next()
                .addClass('after');
        }
        //в самом конце - добавляем пару доп. предыдущих точек
        if(!$this.next().length) {
            $this.prev().prev().prev()
                .addClass('before').prev()
                .addClass('before').prev()
                .addClass('before');
        }
        //предпоследний элемента - добавляем одну пред. точку
        if(!$this.next().next().length) {
            $this.prev().prev().prev()
                .addClass('before');
        }
    });
    dots.eq(0).click();//кликаем на первую точку

    $('.main_scrool').click(function(){
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        var coordinats = $(link).offset().top;
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:coordinats}, 1000);
        return false;
    });
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.item { height: 300px; color: #fff; }
.i1 { background: #01005e; }
.i2 { background: #f1645d; }
.i3 { background: #5d145d; }

/* see here: */
.slick-slide { transition: transform 0.5s ease; }
.slick-current + .slick-slide ~ .slick-slide { transform: translateX(-50%); }
#slick-slide-control00{
  background: #01005e
}
#slick-slide-control01{
  background: #f1645d
}
#slick-slide-control02{
  background: #5d145d
}
#slick-slide-control03{
  background: #01005e
}
#slick-slide-control04{
  background: #f1645d
}
#slick-slide-control05{
  background: #5d145d
}
.slick-dots li{
  display: none
}
.slick-dots li.after, .slick-dots li.before{
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="item i1"><h3>1</h3></div>
  <div class="item i2"><h3>2</h3></div>
  <div class="item i3"><h3>3</h3></div>
  <div class="item i1"><h3>4</h3></div>
  <div class="item i2"><h3>5</h3></div>
  <div class="item i3"><h3>6</h3></div>
</div>
```

Comment: не совсем понятно, какие `dots` выводить? Если текущий активный слайд первый, какие по счету `dots` нужно вывести? 2-3-4? или 3-4-5?

Comment: если активный первый, то выводить нужно 4,5,6-й дотсы, если второй, то выводить 5,6,1, если третий, то 6,2,1 и так далее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже в вашем случае придется реализовать собственные кнопки управления. Что бы все выглядело логично ( так так требуется перестановка элементов, что бы за 6 шла единица )

```js
const $dotsContainer = $('.slider-dots');
const $slider = $(".slider").slick({
  infinite: true,
 slidesToScroll: 1,
 slidesToShow: 2,
});

// реализуем свои кнопки управления
$dotsContainer.on('click', function ({target}) {
  const index = $(target).attr('data-slide');
  
  $slider.slick('slickGoTo', index);
});

// событие смены слайда
$slider.on('afterChange', function () {
    const sliderLength = $slider.slick('getSlick').slideCount;
    const visibleDotsStart = $(this).slick('slickCurrentSlide') + 3; // активный слайд
    
    $dotsContainer.empty(); // очищаем все элементы
    for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      // вся магия в сточке ниже, мы просто считаем индексы
      // которые нужно показать. Нам нужен именно остаток
      // что бы после последнего элемента мы перепрыгнули к первому
      const index = (visibleDotsStart + i) % sliderLength;
      const $dot = $('<div></div>');
      $dot.addClass(`slick-slide-control0${index}`);
      $dot.attr('data-slide', index);
      $dotsContainer.append($dot);
    }
});

$slider.slick('slickGoTo', 0);
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.item { height: 300px; color: #fff; }
.i1 { background: #01005e; }
.i2 { background: #f1645d; }
.i3 { background: #5d145d; }

/* see here: */
.slick-slide { transition: transform 0.5s ease; }
.slick-current + .slick-slide ~ .slick-slide { transform: translateX(-50%); }

.slider-dots {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.slider-dots div{
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider-dots .slick-slide-control00 {
  background: #01005e
}
.slider-dots .slick-slide-control01{
  background: #f1645d
}
.slider-dots .slick-slide-control02{
  background: #5d145d
}
.slider-dots .slick-slide-control03{
  background: #01005e
}
.slider-dots .slick-slide-control04{
  background: #f1645d
}
.slider-dots .slick-slide-control05{
  background: #5d145d
}

.slider-dots div{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="item i1"><h3>1</h3></div>
  <div class="item i2"><h3>2</h3></div>
  <div class="item i3"><h3>3</h3></div>
  <div class="item i1"><h3>4</h3></div>
  <div class="item i2"><h3>5</h3></div>
  <div class="item i3"><h3>6</h3></div>
</div>
<div class='slider-dots'></div>
```

Comment: ThisMan невероятно! Спасибо вам огромнейшее!!!